# Structuring your Flask project the right way (no Blueprint)

Tags: flask, configuration, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate, flask-script

#### Intro

I've read like a thousand posts on SO and other sites trying to figure out what's wrong with my Flask structure and why I can't seem to figure out something. As a last resort, I decided to finally ask the question here.

My project is really simple:

1. I have to fetch some data from some networking devices via API, process the data and store it in a Postgresql DB (most part of the code is in `lib/`).
2. This project is going to be deployed on multiple environments (test, dev, staging and prod).

To do the above I'm using the following:

- [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/) + [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) + [Flask-Script](https://flask-script.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - all of these for handling migrations and DB related operations;
- [Python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) - for handling sensitive configuration data

---

#### Project details

My project structure looks like this:

```
my_project/
├── api/  
├── app.py             
├── config.py
├── __init__.py
├── lib/
│   ├── exceptions.py
│   └── f5_bigip.py
├── log.py
├── logs/
├── manage.py
├── migrations/
├── models/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── model1.py
│   └── model2.py
└── run.py
```

My **app.py** looks like this:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()


def create_app():
    load_dotenv()

    app = Flask(__name__)

    environment = app.config['ENV']

    if environment == 'production':
        app.config.from_object('config.ProductionConfig')
    elif environment == 'testing':
        app.config.from_object('config.TestingConfig')
    else:
        app.config.from_object('config.DevelopmentConfig')

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    return app
```

My **config.py** looks like this:

```py
import os

from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class BaseConfig:
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False

    DB_DRIVERNAME = os.getenv('DB_DRIVERNAME')
    DB_HOST = os.getenv('DB_HOST')
    DB_PORT = os.getenv('DB_PORT')
    DB_NAME = os.getenv('DB_NAME')
    DB_USERNAME = os.getenv('DB_USERNAME')
    DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')

    DB = {
        'drivername': DB_DRIVERNAME,
        'host': DB_HOST,
        'port': DB_PORT,
        'database': DB_NAME,
        'username': DB_USERNAME,
        'password': DB_PASSWORD,
    }

    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = URL(**DB)
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False


class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    DEBUG = True


class TestingConfig(BaseConfig):
    TESTING = True


class StagingConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    DEBUG = True


class ProductionConfig(BaseConfig):
    pass
```

My **__init__.py** looks like this:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# here, create_engine needs the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
# how do I get it from the proper config?
engine = create_engine()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """
    Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations.
    """
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Something went wrong here: {str(e)}. rolling back.')
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

My **manage.py** looks like this:

```py
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import MigrateCommand

from app import create_app


from models import *


manager = Manager(create_app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

My **models/model1.py** looks like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import INET
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

from app import db


class Model1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'model1'

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    ip_address = db.Column(INET, unique=True, nullable=False)
    last_update = db.Column(db.DateTime(), server_default=func.now())

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Model1: {self.ip_address}>'

    def __init__(self, ip_address):
        self.ip_address = ip_address
```

---

#### Questions

Now, I have three main questions:

1. In my main `__init__.py` how can I import `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` from the app's config?
2. Having the `Session()` object in the `__init__.py` doesn't seem too intuitive. Should it be placed in other places? For more context, the `session` is used in `lib/f5_bigip.py` and is probably going to be used in the `api/` as well.
3. Is the overall project structure ok?

Comment: I know this might be considered *opinion based* but most of the questions out there seem to either be focusing on Blueprint or have the whole code in the same file, which is not the case with this question. Also, the title might be a bit misleading so if anyone thinks of a better one, please help me improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions 1 and 2 are directly related to the part of your project that I found strange, so instead of answering those questions I'll just give you a much simpler and better way.

It seems in `__init__.py` you are implementing your own database sessions, just so that you can create a scoped session context manager. Maybe you've got that code from another project? It is not nicely integrated with the rest of your project, which uses the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension, you are just ignoring Flask-SQLAlchemy, which manages your database connections and sessions, and basically creating another connection into the database and new sessions.

What you should do instead is leverage the connections and sessions that Flask-SQLAlchemy provides. I would rewrite `__init__.py` as follows (doing this by memory, so excuse minor mistakes):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

from app import db


@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """
    Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations.
    """
    try:
        yield db.session
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Something went wrong here: {str(e)}. rolling back.')
        db.session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        db.session.close()
```

With this you are reusing the connection/sessions from Flask-SQLAlchemy. Your question 1 then is not a problem anymore. For question 2, you would use `db.session` anywhere in your app where you need database sessions.

Regarding question 3 I think you're mostly okay. I would suggest you do not use Flask-Script, which is a fairly old and unmaintained extension. Instead you can move your CLI to Flask's own CLI support.

Comment: Nice answer, @Miguel! It really makes sense now. What I don't fully understand is the following: Looking at my `lib/` folder,  I'd like to somehow run a file from there within my app's context. The problem is that in that file, I'm using the `session_scope` context manager, and when I run that script standalone, of course it will raise an error saying: `RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context`. Now the question is: how can I *bind*/*attach* that script to my flask up?

Comment: The problem is that you decided to use Flask-SQLAlchemy for your database, so mixing this with plain SQLAlchemy is going to generate duplicate connections as I explain in my answer. You have two options, 1. use Flask-SQLAlchemy everywhere, which means you have to create a Flask app instance even when you are not running the Flask web server. 2. use a different set of db support code for stand-alone scripts vs. web application. Implementing 1 is fairly easy, 2 not so much.

Comment: got it. What about my concern regarding the last comment? Could you please edit your answer and add a few information about that as well? I’m sure it’s going to be useful information for a lot of people! Thanks a lot for your time and the effort put into this

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by bind/attach. You just need to create `app` and `db` in the same way you do for the web app.

Comment: my question can be interpreted more as: How do I access my flask config (dev/test/staging/etc) from within a folder which doesn't know flask's context (external module basically) ^_^. In my case, that would be a ` .py` script from the `lib/` folder which needs to access some config data from the main config of the whole FLASK APP

Comment: You need to create a Flask application instance and load the proper config on it. Then you can create an app context every time you need to use `db`. See how to "manually push a context" in the Flask docs: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/#manually-push-a-context.